# How to Merge Column of Clusters and Columns with X-Y coord?

Tags: mysql, r, merge, coordinates

I have a column with the name of the points, a column with the X coordinates and a column with Y coordinates.

This is the tab on which I'm working:

[image]

I want to create a tab in which I have three columns, one with `Clusters`' ID, one with X coordinates and another with Y coordinates. And for each `ckustr` I want the X-Y coordinates.

I've tried the following code:

```
Xcoord <- sort(unique(tabprof$X_coord))

clusters <- sort(unique(tabprof$Cluster_ID))
```

I've tried do this in order to merge the two vectors, but it wasn't possible, because they have a different number of rows. It's probably due to the presence of clusters with the same X coord value.

Comment: Please don't share data as a picture, we can't copy that. Try to give a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to our talk in comments, I'll provide new solution. I'll use fake data.

```
A <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
B <- c(3,3,4,4,3,3,3,5)
df <- data.frame(A,B)
res <- unique(df)


> df
  A B
1 1 3
2 1 3
3 1 4
4 1 4
5 2 3
6 2 3
7 2 3
8 2 5

> res
  A B
1 1 3
3 1 4
5 2 3
8 2 5
```

So as  you se if our A column is ClusterID and B X-coords, we have ClusterID duplicated but! we have unique coord to each one. What is more if two different IDs have the same coords it's no problem.
I hope that it'll helpful.

Comment: Thanks,but wath I want is: A column with Clusters' ID (only one in each row, without reps), and two columns with X-Y coord, in order to have for each Cluster's ID a value of X-Y coordinates.

Comment: Hmmm. So you need 1st column with unique clisterID and then columns with coords responding to each clusterID?